# How to install Ubuntu on HP Split x2

Tags: system-installation

I would like to install Ubuntu 13.10 on this laptop. I have a USB installation disk. When I boot up with it I get to the menu with option to try Ubuntu without installing. When I select this option screen goes blank.

**Specs**
HP Split 13 x2 PC
Processor: Intel Core i5-4202Y 1.60-GHz processor (3.00-MB L3 cache, dual core, 4.5 W)
Chipset: Integrated system on chip (SoC) platform controller hub (PCH)
Graphics Internal graphics: Intel high-definition graphics Support for HD decode, DX11, HDMI, and PX 5.0 Panel
13.3-in (1920×1080), full high-definition (FHD),light emitting diode (LED), AntiGlare (AG) TouchScreen with MultiTouch enabled; 16:9 wide aspect ratio; typical brightness: 400 nits; slim (3.0-mm), UWVA, support for eDP
13.3-in (1366×768), HD, LED, AG, TouchScreen with MultiTouch enabled; 16:9 wide
aspect ratio; typical brightness: 200 nits; slim (3.0-mm), support for eDP

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The [If you are trying to install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076) answer to [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075) may help. If *none* of the information there or in the other answers to that question enables you to solve the problem, please let us know, by editing this question of yours to include a detailed description of everything you tried and what happened. We might close this as a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075), but it'll be reviewed for reopening if it's edited.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your download with MD5 checksums. If it turns out to be okay, try burning it to a disk and booting from the disk.

Those are my ideas!

Regards,
Ronak Chatterjee
10 Year old
Tech Savvy